# What's wrong with my robot framework teardown?

Tags: robotframework, teardown

I'm new to using robot framework and I'm struggling to get my teardown to work.
It currently looks like:

```
[Teardown]  run keyword if any tests failed  KeyFail
```

When I run the program with code like this, I get the error: Keyword 'Run Keyword If Any Tests Failed' can only be used in suite teardown.

I can change it so that I put it inside it's own test case, however I then get the error that: Test Case contains no keywords.

Please advise me as to what I'm doing wrong. It would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

```
***Keywords***
Generation
    (Some stuff)
KeyFail
    log to console  Error report being sent.


***Test Cases***
Requires successful generation of file
    Generation
Teardown Case
    [Teardown]  run keyword if any tests failed  KeyFail
```

Edit: And how to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: more information would be helpful.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have defined it in the *test case* teardown instead of the test [*suite* teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown). You can change it to use the Test teardown instead.

Edit: Here are two solutions:
1. Change your keyword to the TEST specific one, [Run Keyword If Test Failed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Test%20Failed) which applies to the last executed test, and can only be used in a test teardown.
2. The second is to use Suite Setups / teardowns. These apply to ALL test cases that you run. Like this:

```
***Settings***
Suite Setup    Your Test Setup Keyword
Suite Teardown  run keyword if any tests failed  KeyFail

***Keywords***
Generation
    (Some stuff)
KeyFail
    log to console  Error report being sent.


***Test Cases***
Requires successful generation of file
    Generation
Teardown Case
    Stuff to do
    # teardown is automatic, and does not need to be called.
```